# Can a linkedlist store different data types?

Tags: java, memory-management, data-structures, types, linked-list

My question is very general. I just started studying data structures and I came by linked-lists. I understood they are a sequence of nodes. Each node can store some data and it knows the next node in the list.

So one node has an object O and a pointer to the next object called object B which in turn has another pointer .. until we get to the node which has a pointer to null.

But say I am storing integers in a node in a Linked-list that is pointing to another node holding a string. First, is it allowable? And second, how would this be ever useful?

Also, what are the most common operations done on a linkedlist?
`getSize()`, `remove()`, `insert()`, `getElement()`, `concatenate()`

If I were to store a million mobile number, would it be efficient to use a linkedlist? If not, where would the optimal use of a linkedlist appear?

Since a `LinkedList` is stored randomly in memory(using pointers from one node to another) not like an array adjacent, would this make it harder in NON- auto garbage collection languages like `C++/C` in terms of memory allocation and free-ing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But say I am storing integers in a node in a Linked-list that is pointing to another node holding a string. First, is it allowable? And second, how would this be ever useful?

Yes, it's allowed as long as the list is declared as `List<Object>` or `List<Serializable>`, which both String and Integer extend/implement.

In this particular case, it wouldn't be very useful. But consider a `List<Vehicle>`. It could store instances of Car, Bike, Truck or any other kind of Vehicle.

> what are the most common operations done on a linkedlist?

Those that are documented in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). I would say that adding and iterating are probably the most common. But I haven't make any statistical measurement.

> If I were to store a million mobile number, would it be efficient to use a linkedlist?

It depends on the operation you need to do on the list. If you just need to add at the beginning or the end, it will be O(1). Iterating is not a problem. Finding the index of a phone would be O(n). Accessing at a given index in the list would also be O(n).

In general, an ArrayList is much faster than a LinkedList for almost every use-case. The only use-case where a LinkedList is faster is when it always inserts at the biginning, or when it removes/inserts elements while iterating using its Iterator.

> would this make it harder in NON- auto garbage collection languages like C++/C in terms of memory allocation and free-ing?

I'm not experiences enough in those languages to answer, but yes, since you have to manage the memory, it's harder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,Sure according to heading of question,the answer is very simple and easy.
You can insert any data type values in the linked list I've designed and its very simple to do so.I have used different constructors of node and boolean variables to check that which type value is inserted and then I do operation and command according to that value in my program.

```
//IMPLEMENTATION OF SINGLY LINKED LISTS
#include"iostream"
#include"conio.h"
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace  std;



class node //struct
{
public:
    node* nextptr;
    int data;
    ////////////////////////////////just to asure that user can insert any data type value in the linked list
    string ss;
    char cc;
    double dd;
    bool stringTrue=0;
    bool intTrue = 0;
    bool charTrue = 0;
    bool doubleTrue = 0;
    ////////////////////////////////just to asure that user can insert any data type value in the linked list
    node()
    {
        nextptr = NULL;
    }
    node(int d)
    {
        data = d;
        nextptr = NULL;
        intTrue = 1;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////just to asure that user can insert any data type value in the linked list
    node(string s)
    {
        stringTrue = 1;
        ss = s;
        nextptr = NULL;
    }
    node(char c)
    {
        charTrue = 1;
        cc = c;
        nextptr = NULL;
    }
    node(double d)
    {
        doubleTrue = 1;
        dd = d;
        nextptr = NULL;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////just to asure that user can insert any data type value in the linked list
    //TO Get the data
    int getintData()
    {
        return data;
    }
    string getstringData()
    {
        return ss;
    }
    double getdoubleData()
    {
        return dd;
    }
    char getcharData()
    {
        return cc;
    }
    //TO Set the data
    void setintData(int d)
    {
        data = d;
    }
    void setstringData(string s)
    {
        ss = s;
    }
    void setdoubleData(double d)
    {
        dd = d;
    }
    void setcharData(char c)
    {
        cc = c;
    }
    char checkWhichInput()
    {
        if (intTrue == 1)
        {
            return 'i';
        }
        else if (stringTrue == 1)
        {
            return 's';
        }
        else if (doubleTrue == 1)
        {
            return 'd';
        }
        else if (charTrue == 1)
        {
            return 'c';
        }
    }
    //////////////////////////////Just for the sake of implementing for any data type//////////////////////////////
    node* getNextptr()
    {
        return nextptr;
    }
    void setnextptr(node* nptr)
    {
        nextptr = nptr;
    }
};


class linkedlist
{
    node* headptr;
    node* addnodeatspecificpoition;
    
public:
    linkedlist()
    {
        headptr = NULL;
    }
    void insertionAtTail(node* n)
    {
        if (headptr == NULL)
        {
            headptr = n;
        }
        else
        {
            node* rptr = headptr;
            while (rptr->getNextptr() != NULL)
            {
                rptr = rptr->getNextptr();
            }
            rptr->setnextptr(n);
        }
    }

    void insertionAtHead(node *n)
    {
        node* tmp = n;
        tmp->setnextptr(headptr);
        headptr = tmp;
    }

    int sizeOfLinkedList()
    {
        int i = 1;
        node* ptr = headptr;
        while (ptr->getNextptr() != NULL)
        {
            ++i;
            ptr = ptr->getNextptr();
        }
        return i;
    }

    bool isListEmpty() {
        if (sizeOfLinkedList() <= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            false;
        }
    }

    void insertionAtAnyPoint(node* n, int position)
    {
        if (position > sizeOfLinkedList() || position < 1) {
            cout << "\n\nInvalid insertion at index :" << position;
            cout <<".There is no index " << position << " in the linked list.ERROR.\n\n";
            return;
        }

        addnodeatspecificpoition = new node;
        addnodeatspecificpoition = n;
        addnodeatspecificpoition->setnextptr(NULL);

        

        if (headptr == NULL)
        {
            headptr = addnodeatspecificpoition;
        }
        else if (position == 0)
        {
            addnodeatspecificpoition->setnextptr(headptr);
            headptr = addnodeatspecificpoition;
        }
        else
        {
            node* current = headptr;
            int i = 1;
            for (i = 1; current != NULL; i++)
            {
                if (i == position)
                {
                    addnodeatspecificpoition->setnextptr(current->getNextptr());
                    current->setnextptr(addnodeatspecificpoition);
                    break;
                }
                current = current->getNextptr();
            }
        }
    }

 
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output,const linkedlist& L)
    {
        char checkWhatInput;
        int i = 1;
        node* ptr = L.headptr;
        while (ptr->getNextptr() != NULL)
        {
            ++i;
            checkWhatInput = ptr->checkWhichInput();
            /// <summary>
            switch (checkWhatInput)
            {
            case 'i':output <<ptr->getintData()<<endl;
                break;
            case 's':output << ptr->getstringData()<<endl;
                break;
            case 'd':output << ptr->getdoubleData() << endl;
                break;
            case 'c':output << ptr->getcharData() << endl;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="output"></param>
            /// <param name="L"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            
            ptr = ptr->getNextptr();
        }

        /// <summary>
        switch (checkWhatInput)
        {
        case 'i':output << ptr->getintData() << endl;
            break;
        case 's':output << ptr->getstringData() << endl;
            break;
        case 'd':output << ptr->getdoubleData() << endl;
            break;
        case 'c':output << ptr->getcharData() << endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="output"></param>
        /// <param name="L"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>

        if (ptr->getNextptr() == NULL)
        {
            output << "\nNULL (There is no pointer left)\n";
        }
        return output;
    }
    ~linkedlist() {
        delete addnodeatspecificpoition;
    }
};



int main()
{

    linkedlist L1;


    //Insertion at tail
    L1.insertionAtTail(new node("dsaf"));
    L1.insertionAtTail(new node("sadf"));
    L1.insertionAtTail(new node("sfa"));
    L1.insertionAtTail(new node(12));
    L1.insertionAtTail(new node(67));
    L1.insertionAtTail(new node(23));
    L1.insertionAtTail(new node(45.677));
    L1.insertionAtTail(new node(12.43556));


    //Inserting a node at head
    L1.insertionAtHead(new node(1));
    //Inserting a node at any given point
    L1.insertionAtAnyPoint(new node(999), 3);

    cout << L1;

    cout << "\nThe size of linked list after insertion of elements is : " << L1.sizeOfLinkedList();    
}
```

The output is 
1
dsaf
sadf
999
sfa
12
67
23
45.677
12.4356
Thats what you can use to create a linked list without worrying of data type